# Deleted node in BST is set with value 0

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a function for deleting a node in BST. Although deleting is working fine, after deletion of the node and I do a in order traversal, I still see the deleted node with a value of 0. I was expecting to not see the node at all.

For example when deleting node 18, 16 is copied to 18, and the node with value 16 is deleted.

- Inorder traversal before deletion is `[8 10 12 15 16 18 20 25 50]`
- Inorder traversal after deletion is `[8 10 12 15 0 16 20 25 50]`
- What I was expecting `[8 10 12 15 16 20 25 50]`

Here is the code snippet:

```
bool deleteNode(Node *root,int key) {
    if(root) {
        if(key < root->data)
                return deleteNode(root->left,key);
        else if(key > root->data)
                return deleteNode(root->right,key);
        else if(!root->left && !root->right) {
            free(root);
            return true;
        } else if(root->left && !root->right) {
            Node *inorderPre=maxElement(root->left);
            root->data=inorderPre->data;
            return deleteNode(inorderPre,root->data);
        } else {
            Node* inorderSucc=minElement(root->right);
            root->data=inorderSucc->data;
            return deleteNode(inorderSucc,root->data);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Auxiliary functions:

```
Node* minElement(Node *root) {
    while(root->left!=NULL) {
        root=root->left;
    }
    return root;
}

Node* maxElement(Node *root) {
    while(root->right!=NULL) {
        root=root->right;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: You never modify the `left` or `right` pointers

Comment: Do you mean for the node 18 ? so node 18 that needs to be deleted has only one left child and no right child {left child of 18 is 16}. So when I have to delete 18, I copy value 16 in node with value 18, and free(Node(16)). With this I assume that the left child of 18 {Which now has value 16} is now NULL. Does that seem right ?

Comment: Nope. The left child still points to the old block; because you've already freed it, you have a dangling pointer.

Comment: Okay ... I see your point. But to set the left child of 18 to NULL, I need access to parent. Right now I am in my call for node 16, N Since Node 16 has both left and right child NULL, I go for free(node(16)). Now once I do that, I have a dangling pointer {left child of node 18} but I the access to node 18 was in the last call, n now my current stack call is on node 16.     I don't know if it makes sense?? but how should I go back to node 18 to set its left child NULL??

Comment: @user2171983 change Interface from `bool deleteNode(Node *root,int key)` to `bool deleteNode(Node **root,int key)`

Comment: okay .... I changed it from *root to **root. But it is still giving the same results. Actually I was hoping it won't change anything. My understanding is when I was passing a pointer (e.g root), I can receive it in *root. However with your change I am passing the address of a pointer (&root) so I need to receive it in **root (pointer to a pointer). N Now in my entire implementation of deleteNode, I am dereferencing the pointer with (*root) e.g. (*root)->data instead of root->data. I am not sure how that resolves the problem.